# Unable to resolve this maven/apache error

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

I tried to build a web service maven project using jersey in eclipse.

This was the archetype I used:

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting

[image]

I tried re downloading dependancies, deleting and creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding

**compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.19.4'**

dependency explicitly?